# Using offset formula with CountIf for column

Tags: excel, offset, countif

I want to repeat the formula for series of columns. I am in AY4 and using the formula

```
COUNTIF(Sheet1!$K$3:$K$72,$AY2)
```

column(AY) will be increasing like AZ, BA, BB, BC and so on. Can you tell me how to use OFFSET formula for this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If you want to just drag the formula across you could remove the `$` from the `$AY2` and the reference will increase as you drag it across. `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$K$3:$K$72,AY2)`.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. I have removed $ sign and dragged the formula and it worked on multiple columns